# How come sqrt() with which uses a calculation of two pow()'s inside of is wrong in intellisense

Tags: c++, pow, sqrt

I have this code:

```
int findY ( int x, int r) {

return sqrt(pow(x,2) - pow(r,2));

};
```

But for some reason Ms intellisense is flagging it as wrong syntax. I'm not sure why.

Comment: perhaps it wants you to delete the last semicolon after the function

Comment: My guess would be that pow(float, float) is the one that ms recognizes, so pow(int, int) is not "ok".

Comment: There appears to be an account with that name [Johanne Irish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1524907/johanne-irish).  Whether it is yours, I could not say.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Unlikely, since `int` arguments are implicitly promoted to `double` in this context. If Intellisense complained about implicit conversions, you'd drown in warnings. -- Never mind, it's ambiguous (I was thinking in C rather than C++).

Comment: The `pow` function is probably overkill for squaring an integer. I'd write `return sqrt(x*x - r*r);`

Comment: @KeithThompson your intellisense is flagging.  :)

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I don't use this site very often so I tend to forget that I use a less frequently used email for that account. I'd log in and reply with it but for some reason I could not find a reply button when logged in with it. how silly.

Comment: @user62879, You need 50 reputation to comment on questions that are not your own.

Comment: @user62879 click the "my logins" link on [your page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1524907) to add your other email accounts.

Comment: Note: `pow(x,2)` **`<`** `pow(r,2)` and sqrt not defined for `-ve`  numbers` also function return type should be float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error it gives:

```
1>..\main.cpp(7): error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h(583): could be 'long double pow(long double,int)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h(535): or       'float pow(float,int)'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h(497): or       'double pow(double,int)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int, int)'
```

Basically, it's an ambiguous overload. So you need to cast it to clarify:

```
return sqrt(pow((double)x,2.) - pow(((double)r,2.));
```

Not only that, did you really intend the return type to be an int?

Comment: Are any of those actually standard? All I see in my C++11 draft is `(float, float)` and `(long double, long double)`. Even if an implementation is allowed to define more (as sometimes happens across the standard), I would imagine those two are mandatory.

Comment: I doubt it. The Microsoft compiler seems to be adding them to help resolve the ambiguities. But it doesn't have one for int and int.

Comment: I did not entirely need an int as a return type but I wanted to round off the extra digits because the graph I'm using goes out by hundreds in any significant distance. I figured floating point was too precise. I'm working on an experiment that's all. I know casting is a bad idea... I think I'll just change the parameters to floats.

Comment: @chris those mandatory ones may *(must!?)* also be present, but not considered for `sqrt(int, int)`